# $_GET checkbox value not updating after $_POST on search results?

Tags: php, forms, post, checkbox, get

I need my checkboxes to be set by default on search results, unless set on homepage or search results page:

**home.php:**

```
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>">
<select name='test_menu'><option value='test'>test</option></select>
```

**search_results.php:**

```
if ( (isset($_POST['test']) == 'test') || (isset($_GET['test_menu']) == 'test') )
 {
    $test = 'checked="checked"';
 }

...

<form id ="s_form" action="<?php $self ?>" method="post" >

<input type="checkbox" onChange="this.form.submit()" name="test" value="test" <?php echo $test; ?> />
```

The form on the homepage has the **method="get"** and the form on the search results page has method="post".

The search results page has a URL of `&test=test`. if I search from the home page.

After searching from the homepage the $_GET value always remains on the search results page - even when I update the form via $_POST. I want to repost the form on the search results page and have the checkbox unticked after it's been set via the home page. I hope this makes sense.

In conclusion: the checkbox will **not uncheck** if `&test_menu=test` is in the URL, and it should do.

**Update:**
Added form code to show the actions of each form on each page.

Answer (score 3):

the code `isset($_POST['test'])` will return `true`or `false`, so `(isset($_POST['test']) == 'test')`will always be `false`

Use this instead:

```
if (  (isset($_POST['test']) && ($_POST['test'] == 'test')) || (isset($_GET['test_menu']) && ($_GET['test_menu'] == 'test')) )  {
    $test = 'checked="checked"';
}
```

Comment: OK, for some weird reason it doesn't tick the box when $_GET isset now??? Works fine on $_POST though!!!

Comment: I dont' understand : do you want you checkbox to be check with POST when `&test_menu=test` or when `&test=test` or at the contrary when `&test=other`?

Comment: $_GET always returns true.

Comment: What return true? $_GET is an array, not a boolean.

Comment: $_GET[test_menu] == 'test'; - Always!

Answer (score 1):

Modify your code like this

```
if ((isset($_POST['test']) &&  $_POST['test']=='test') 
     || (isset($_GET['test']) &&  $_GET['test']=='test') )
 {
    $test = "checked='checked'";
 }

...

<input type="checkbox" name="test" value="test" <?php echo $test; ?> />
```

mark the change in the line `$test = "checked='checked'";` as well

Answer (score 0):

1) `if ( $_REQUEST['test'] == 'test' )`

2)  to clean up the get variables in your form submission ( in postdata ) you'll rather use an  `action='?'` or `action='<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>'`